# Checking sockets using select() - Winsock

Tags: sockets, winsock

I have been exploring on function `select()` to check if some sockets are ready to read and I must admit that I'm a bit confused.  The MSDN says "The select function returns the total number of socket handles that are ready and contained in the `fd_set` structures".

Suppose I have 3 sockets and 2 sockets are ready, `select()` returns 2, but this gives me no information which 2 of these 3 sockets are ready to read so how can I check it?

On stack overflow I came across this: [When select returns, it has updated the sets to show which file descriptors have become ready for read/write/exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637765/why-fd-set-fd-zero-for-select-inside-of-loop)

So I put breakpoints in my program to track my `fd_set` structure. What I have realized is that ( just one socket in `fd_set`): If socket is ready to read `select()`:

1. returns 1
2. leaves `fd_count` (The number of sockets in the set) untouched
3. leaves `fd_array` (An array of sockets that are in the set.) untouched

If client did not send any data addressed to that socket `select()`:

1. returns 0
2. decreases `fd_count` to 0
3. leaves `fd_array`  untouched

If I call select() again and client again sent no data:

1. return -1 (I think this is because of the `fd_count` value - 0)

I guess I miss some crucial rules how select() works and what this function does but I can't figure out it.
Here is some code snippet to show what I do to call select():

```cpp
CServer::CServer(char *ipAddress,short int portNumber)
{   // Creating socket
    ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (ServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        std::cout << "I was not able to create  ServerSocket\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "ServerSocket created successfully\n";

    // Initialization of ServerSocket Address
    ServerSocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerSocketAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ipAddress);
    ServerSocketAddress.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    // Binding ServerSocket to ServerSocket Address
    if (bind(ServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerSocketAddress, sizeof(ServerSocketAddress)) == 0) 
        std::cout << "Binding ServersSocket and ServerSocketAddress ended with success\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "There were problems with binding ServerSocket and ServerSocket Address\n";

    // Initialization of the set of sockets
    ServerSet.fd_count = 1;
    ServerSet.fd_array[0] = ServerSocket;
}
```

In main :

```cpp
CServer Server(IP_LOOPBACK_ADDRESS, 500);
tmp = select(0, &Server.ServerSet, NULL, NULL, &TimeOut);
```

Should't the `fd_array` be filled with 0 values after the `select()` call, when there is no socket that can be read?

Answer (score 0):

You're suppose to use the [FD_SET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro and friends. You're not doing that.

Comment: Replacing:  ServerSet.fd_count = 1; ServerSet.fd_array[0] = ServerSocket; with FD_ZERO(&Server.ServerSet); FD_SET(Server.ServerSocket, &Server.ServerSet); does not change anything when I call select() 3 times in the order I mentioned above.

Comment: You're suppose to call it every time around the loop. select() uses it destructively.

Comment: When I call it everytime before select() call it works. If I have 2 sockets in fd_set and select() returns 1 how am I supposed to know which socket is ready to be read ? There are still 2 file descriptors in fd_array.

Comment: Ok FD_ISSET works but how !?. Lets say I have: fd_set myset; FD_SET(socket1,&myset); FD_SET(socket2,&myset); Then in locals windows in the debugger I can see that: myset.fd_count = 2, myset.fd_array[0] = 124, myset.fd_array[1] = 136;. After calling select() I can see myset.fd_count = 1, myset.fd_array[0] = 124, myset.fd_array[1] = 136;. But when I call FD_ISSET(Socket1,&myset) I get non zero value, and when I call FD_ISSET(Socket2,&myset) I get 0 value. My question is: How is it possible if only myset.fd_count value changed ?

Comment: `fd_array` and `fd_count` changed to reflect which sockets satisfied `select()`. `select()` simply did not clear out the array slots that are not included in `fd_count`. That is an implementation detail that your code should not care about. `FD_ISSET()` takes `fd_count` into account. You need to call `FD_ISSET()` for every socket you put into the array before calling `select()`.

Comment: Put your sockets into your own list. Every time you want to call `select()`, initialize a new `fd_set` using `FD_ZERO()`, then loop through your list calling `FD_SET()` to add each socket to the `fd_set`, then call `select()`.  If `select()` returns >0, the `fd_set` was altered to contain just the sockets that satisfied `select()` so loop through your list calling `FD_ISSET()` to see which sockets are still in the `fd_set` and act on them accordingly.

Comment: I did like that but I still wonder where is kept the information about which sockets satisfied select() if only **fd_array** changed after select(). I don't know how exactly FD_ISSET() acts.